# Find and replace folder name in path

Tags: bash

In my Bash script, I have a variable that contains a path. Let say:

```
mypath=/a/b/c/d/e
```

I would like to be able and replace the name of the parent folder  of `c/d` by something else (let say `newB`), so as to get:

```
/a/newB/c/d/e
```

How can I do that?
I've tried my best to combine cut, sed and awk but I'm getting awfully long commands without getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's#^(.*/)[^/]+(/c/d/)#\1newB\2#'
```

- `(.*/)` matches upto the `/` (and put in captured group 1), followed by one or more characters that are not `/` (`[^/]+`)
- The second captured group, `(/c/d/)`, matches `/c/d/` literally
- In the replacement the parent of `/c/d/` is replaced with `newB` and the captured groups are kept expectedly

**Example:**

```
% mypath=/a/b/c/d/e                               

% sed -E 's#^(.*/)[^/]+(/c/d/)#\1newB\2#' <<<"$mypath"
/a/newB/c/d/e
```

Comment: The fact is I know the pattern `/c/d/` but not its parent name. So I can't specify `b` in the sed expression.

Comment: Great! I accept this answer as it is a one liner and also works with a ZSH shell (not in the requirements but a plus for me).

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter expansion.

```
#!/bin/bash
mypath=/a/b/c/d/e
parent=${mypath%/c/d/*}
suffix=${mypath#*/c/d/}
grandparent=${parent%/*}

newpath=$grandparent/newB/c/d/$suffix
echo $newpath
```

With `extglob`, you can use substitution, which simplifies the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mypath=/a/b/c/d/e

shopt -s extglob
pattern=+([^/])/c/d
newpath=${mypath/$pattern/newB/c/d}
echo $newpath
```